How to implement sign up with phone after having email in aws Cognito?
I currently have a React Native project that uses AWS Cognito for user sign-up with Google or email, with email set as a required attribute:

As per documentation, we can't update these Required attributes

Is there a way to keep using the same User Pool, but adding the option to ask for the phone number during the sign up for the new users? Also having the option for the user to receive the SMS to confirm the number.
